# Why can I return local int& and get certain value instead of trash? C++

Tags: c++, return, local

I am wondering what happens when you return int&. Lets jump to the example.
I have a simple class Foobar storing one int.
Lets have a look at this function:

```
Foobar showObjectsValue() {
    Foobar b(50);
    return b;
}
```

It returns copy of a local object so when I call this function I actually get some data instead of some trash. But when I do something like this:

```
Foobar& showObjectsValue() {
    Foobar b(50);
    return b;
}
```

It returns garbage because after we exit scope of the "showObjectsValue()"  object "b" gets popped from the memory stack and we return reference to this popped object (correct me if I am wrong). But I don't know what is happening in case of returning int instead of object.

This function:

```
int& showIntegerValue() {
    int i = 50;
    return i;
}
```

and this function:

```
int showIntegerValue() {
    int i = 50;
    return i;
}
```

return the same value, both give me int = 50. So can someone explain what actually is going on in case of returning reference to local integer and local object?

Comment: Note: an `int` is an object. You have undefined behavior.

Comment: It's not my intention to label you as a know-it-all, but that question does cover the "is it really undefined behavior when it looks like it works fine?" confusion which appears to be the core of your question.

Comment: Oh I didn't know int is also an object. Good to know it was ub. Thanks.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: never.

Comment: _It returns copy of a local object_ Not necessary, this looks like a perfect case for copy elision

Comment: Undefined behavior means that *anything* can happen. "Seems to work" is only one of many possible results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So can someone explain what actually is going on in case of returning reference to local integer and local object?

Integers *are* objects. Trying to access an alias to a destroyed object is undefined behavior. Don't expect anything from it. Your compiler should even give you a warning about this:

```
main.cpp:4:9: warning: reference to local variable 'i' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     int i = 50;
```

In the end, when you're dealing with undefined behavior, just because you see something doesn't mean it is expected. To further prove this point, trying to run this code with [GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DQ7uZREXPO4pZiZT) results in the warning above and a segmentation fault.